# Use map[string]SpecificType with method of map[string]SomeInterface into

Tags: go

I get `cannot use map[string]MyType literal (type map[string]MyType) as type map[string]IterableWithID in argument to MapToList` with the code below, how do I pass in a concrete map type to method that expects a interface type?

https://play.golang.org/p/G7VzMwrRRw

Comment: They are both concrete map types.  One of them has an interface value type.  Write a for loop to construct the `map[string]IterableWithID` from a `map[string]MyType`.

Comment: I should have said "pass a map of a concrete type to a method that has a map of an interface type in the signature". MyType implements IterableWithID but the compiler says it's not valid.

Comment: My point is that is that the values have different concrete types.  It's not possible to assign one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Go's interface convention doesn't quite work the same way as in, say, Java (and the designers apparently didn't like the idea of getters and setters very much :-/ ).  So you've got two core problems:

1. A map[string]Foo is not the same as a map[string]Bar, even if Bar implements Foo, so you have to break it out a bit (use make() beforehand, then assign in a single assignment).
2. Interface methods are called by value with no pointers, so you really need to do foo = foo.Method(bar) in your callers or get really pointer-happy to implement something like this.

What you can do to more-or-less simulate what you want:

```
type IterableWithID interface {
    SetID(id string) IterableWithID     // use as foo = foo.SetID(bar)
}

func (t MyType) SetID(id string) IterableWithID {
    t.ID = id
    return t
}

...and to deal with the typing problem

t := make(map[string]IterableWithID)
t["foo"] = MyType{}
MapToList(t)              // This is a map[string]IterableWithID, so compiler's happy. 

...and finally...

value = value.SetID(key)  // We set back the copy of the value we mutated
```

The final value= deals with the fact that the method gets a fresh copy of the value object, so the original would be untouched by your method (the change would simply vanish).

Updated code on [the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OgFjTFw_LZ)

...but it's not particularly idiomatic Go--they really want you to just reference struct members rather than use Java-style mutators in interfaces (though TBH I'm not so keen on that little detail--mutators are supes handy to do validation).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want to do because the two map types are different. It doesn't matter that the element type of one is a type that implements the interface which is the element type of the other. The map type that you pass into the function has to be `map[string]IterableWithID`. You could create a map of that type, assign values of type `MyType` to the map, and pass that to the function.

See https://play.golang.org/p/NfsTlunHkW

Also, you probably don't want to be returning a pointer to a slice in `MapToList`. Just return the slice itself. A slice contains a reference to the underlying array.